# ng test時のconfigureTestingModuleの定義について

Tags: angularjs, angular2, angular4, jasmine

ng testにてUnitTestの実行を試みておりますが、
各importやconfigureTestingModule()の定義をテスト対象が使っている子Component/Service/Module/etc...をいちいち定義しなおさなければならず、Testそのもの以外の負荷を億劫に感じております。
気持ち的にはTestで頻出する定義は一か所にまとめたり、AppModuleの@NgModuleで定義されているものを一気に設定したいのですが、何かそのような方法はございますでしょうか？

- 各spec.tsファイルはng gコマンドで各coponent/service生成時に同時に自動生成されたものをベースに作っております。
- AngularのVersionは4ですが、AngularJSの情報でも助かります。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319091/testbed-configuretestingmodule-define-imports-declarations-providers-and-pipe 同様質問あり(現時点回答なし)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

完全に省略はできませんが以下の方法で作業軽減しています。

router-stubs.ts

```
//----------Default Import------------
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...snip...
export const test_imports = [
               BrowserModule,
               FormsModule,
               HttpModule,
               BrowserAnimationsModule
             ];
```

test.spec.ts

```
import { test_imports }   from '../testing/router-stubs';
..snip..
      imports: [test_imports],
```